# Assign a specific value to a cell from a range depending on sheet name

Tags: vba, range

I am trying to assign a different number from a range to the same cell in different sheets.

For example, I have range c4:c9.  In Sheet A, A1=c4; Sheet B, A1=c5; Sheet C, A1=c6; etc.

I cannot make my macro move down the range.

Instead for each sheet it assigns C4 to A1.

I currently have the sheets named in a range so VBA will know to move sheets.

Here is my code:

```
Sub update()

   Dim sheet_name As Range
        For Each sheet_name In Sheets("Home").Range("A4:A9")
        If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
    Else
        Sheets(sheet_name.Value).Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=Home!r[3]c[2]"
        Range("A2").Select

    End If

    Next sheet_name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

sheet_name is not a range.  While the strings inside the cells may be sheet names, they aren't sheets.

So:

```
Sub test()
Dim sSheetName As String

For Each cell In [sheetnames]
    sSheetName = cell.Value
    Sheets(sSheetName).Range("a1") = "some formula"
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: That did not answer my question.  I want A!a2=Home!c4, B!a2=Home!c5, and so on.  I am using the sheet_name as a range to go to each sheet.  Now I need the values of cell "a2" in each sheet move down a range in sheet "Home"

Comment: I guess I'm still having trouble visualizing the problem.

Comment: So where cell a2 = 3, you want to get the third value in another range on Home?  Maybe you could drop box a sample so I can see it?